# LINQ for cumulative records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ado.net, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have two entities called `Patients` and `TelephoneCallsHistory` with *1-m* Relationship.

The query is below,
[image]

The data model is

[image]

The following is the sample telephone data
[image]

I would like to return the patient records where the contact outcome is Call Back is Required provided in the next few records there is no Contact Purpose is Completed. Basically I'm trying to create an alert/notification for user to follow up.

I have come up with following code

```
query = query
     .Where(m => !m.PatientsMasterItem
             .PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail.Any(l => l.Status == "1"));
```

But it doesn't work in the above given example(refer test data). But still the last record requires action to follow up.

Comment: Two questions. Can you show your domain model? What is the initial value of query?

Comment: And how is your screenshot related to your query?

Comment: The screenshot is showing sample data for one patient. The status 1 refers to "Contact Purpose Completed"

Answer (score 1):

This is not compiled - this is only a hint. You need something likeSomething like

```
        var required = query.Where(DoesPatientNeedCallback);

        public static bool DoesPatientNeedCallback(Patient p)
        {
              var last = p.PatientsMasterItem.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail.LastOrDefault(c => c.Status == 'Contact Required' || c.Status == 'Contact Purpose Completed);
              return last != null && last.Status == 'Contact Required'

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete code is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch;
using Microsoft.LightSwitch.Security.Server;

namespace LightSwitchApplication
{
public partial class ApplicationDataService
{

    partial void StatusCallBackRequired_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail> query)
    {
        var required = query.Where(PatientNeedCallback);

    }

    public static bool PatientNeedCallback(PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail p)
    {
        var last = p.PatientsMasterItem.PatientsTelephoneFollowupDetail.LastOrDefault(c => c.Status == "7" || c.Status == "1");
        return last != null && last.Status == "7";

    }
}    


}
```